# Fix position DIV until collide with other element

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have 2 DIV one is a Polymer with dom-repeat, which will repeat the DOM inside of it but another DIV need to fix position until first DIV extend to collide

```
<div> Text </div> . // This have DOM-REPEAT
<div class="fix"> </div> . // Need to fix position until get collide
```

The div class "fix" need to contain the original position until the first DIV have expand and collide with "fix" element then change to "relative"

Is there anyway to do this ? 
I have tried margin and padding but it not work at all

Comment: Only JS could help this case, wait me a second

Comment: After confuse for a day, I have fixed this by using min-height

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, vote up if u think it helps

```css
.outter {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.fixed-one {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
    <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
    <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div>  content content</div>
  <div class="fixed-one">
    I am fix
  </div>
</div>
```